# 2012 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, status-completed, election, moderators

The 2012 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.

Please visit the official election page at

https://security.stackexchange.com/election

for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

Answer (score 5):

In an effort to find some of the information that may be useful to the site users for the upcoming election here are things that I thought might be useful. They're certainly not in any particular order, but are grouped by where the data comes from. I plan to add more as I come across them.

## Main Site Database Queries

The last data dump was June 27th, 2012, so all data will be up-to-date as of then.

- [Distribution of User Activity Per UTC Hour](http://data.stackexchange.com/it%20security/query/8009/distribution-of-user-activity-per-hour) -- Must currently be run per user. User IDs for current mods and candidates are:

  - Rory Alsop - 485
  - AviD - 33
  - Hendrik Brummermann - 665
  - Terry Chia - 10211
  - Scott Pack - 618
  - Iszi - 953
  - Polynomial - 5400
  - bethlakshmi - 1080
- [Top 50 Most Prolific Editors](http://data.stackexchange.com/it%20security/query/6627/top-50-most-prolific-editors) (sorted by total, broken out by question/answer edits)

## Stack Apps

[Moderator Candidate Statistics](http://elections.stackexchange.com/#security.stackexchange) - Merges election page with various user statistics including select list of badges, voting records, network wide data, etc.

Comment: Great links, there.  Thanks!  I wonder if there's a way to query chat activity?

Comment: Individually yes by way of their user page. Though the trick is aggregating that data for everyone. There's no reason why an app could be made to accept a list of uids and generate a stacked graph. The trick is learning the API and doing it.

Comment: The number of edits is visible on the [main site](http://security.stackexchange.com/users?tab=editors&filter=all) now. It's more reliable than the query you link to (which only counts the last editor at the time of the dump). Note that the count includes tag-only edits.

Comment: @Gilles Then edit and fix the link.

Comment: I am pretty sure that the time profile, when I handle flags, is quite different from, when I have sufficient time to write postings.